# Need git team development experience

Tags: git, branch, collaboration, branching-strategy

I don't know may I ask such question here, but I gonna try. I'm working in a software development team and we use `GIT` to control our development process. We have our own gitlab where our projects are located. And each developer has its own clone of project on the local machine. We don't have direct access to files, when we have to push changes we ask our administators to push master branch to release version (if I describe it correct). We use skype chat to ask admins about pushing changes and sometimes it needs long time while they response and **important changes stay long being not updated**.

So my question is how can we make this process more smart (or more reliable). I mean it usually makes in the world companies. Thanks

Comment: Not every developer on the team *needs* the ability to write to the release branch. That said, you can look into the concepts of *continuous integration* and *continuous delivery* as examples of how the deployment process can be simplified down to a single click of a button, without compromising quality assurance.

Answer (score 1):

Time is paid with money and quality is paid with time. If developers can push directly into a repository, quality inevitably deteriorates. That's why [all Git teams eventually turn to a gatekeeper / dictatorship model](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

The advantage of Git is that you don't need a linear process. Git is quite clever to apply changes to different branches. This means that you can continue to work, even when your pull request isn't accepted, yet.

If the PR is rejected, you can go back in time, do the fixes, tack your new work back at the end using `git rebase`.

Atlassian has a [good tutorial on Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/) and why you should do certain things in a certain way.

I have been through the same process. Git takes some time to get used to it, mostly because it has so many features and as a beginner, you don't know which ones are better than others or which are dangerous.